# How to join strings into one sentence separated by spaces

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, newline

I have this code:

```
with open("wordslist.txt") as f:
    words_list = {word.removesuffix("\n") for word in f}

with open("neg.csv") as g:
    for tweete in g:
        for word in tweete.split():
            if word not in words_list:
                print(word)
```

and the output is like this:

```
gfg
best
gfg
I
am
I
two
two
three
..............
```

I want to remove the newline (enter) so it will be one big sentence (there are like 4500+ words). How to join the words and remove the newline (replace each newline with space) so it became one big sentence.

I expected the output to be like this:

```
gfg best gfg I am I two two three..............
```

Comment: can you please share the expected output as well.

Comment: I already edited my question!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append them to a list and than do " ".join(your_list)
Or you can create an empty string x = ""
And in in your iteration do smth like x += word

Here is example for the 1st solution

```
import csv

# Open the CSV file and read its contents
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(reader)  # Skip the header row
    
    # Initialize an empty list to store the column values
    column_values = []
    
    # Retrieve the values from the specified column and append them to the list
    for row in reader:
        column_values.append(row[0])  # Replace 0 with the index of the desired column
        
    # Create a sentence with whitespace between the words
    sentence = ' '.join(column_values)
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: Actually yes, the solution of Jack is good also with print(word, end=" ") Even better